# Menu in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

Good day. 
Could you, please explain me one thing with the menu component in ionic 2.
I've wrote this code:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item (click)="open(profileRoot)">Profile</button>
            <button ion-item (click)="open(farmPage)">Farms</button>
            <button ion-item (click)="open(feedsRoot)">Feeds</button>
            <button ion-item (click)="open(calculatorRoot)">Calculator</button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="calculatorRoot"></ion-nav>
```

And in each component I have this code:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
<ion-buttons start>
    <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
<ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content class="calculator-page">
    Profile
</ion-content>
```

But, the thing is - the menu icon appears on iOS as it should be, on the left, but on android devices it appears at the right. 
Could somebody explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because css is different for Android & iOS.

If you inspect the `<ion-buttons>`, you will see :

- for Android

`ion-buttons {
    order: 4;
}`

- for iOS

`ion-buttons {
    order: 3;
}`

This is FLEX order, which determine the position of the button.

If you want the same position on iOS & Android, you should write in your `app.md.scss` :

`ion-buttons {
    order: 3;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The Ionic2 Android md theme does not include settings for `.ion-button[start]`, even though it includes settings for `.ion-button[end]`.

I found that using the `left` (and `right`) attributes worked as expected, so just change `<ion-buttons start>` to `<ion-buttons left>`:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
<ion-buttons left>
    <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
<ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content class="calculator-page">
    Profile
</ion-content>
```

I have not seen documentation on when to use start/end vs. left/right. While overriding the flex order directly in the css will work in your specific case, it *may* cause buttons in the rest of your application to be out of order.